# Direct connect router UART 3.3v to pi3B UART 3.3v and use debug console

Tags: uart, communication, serial-console, debug, 64-bit

Can I use a Raspberry PI model B to interact directly to a router debug console (undocumented) via "screen".

```
TX  <-> RX
RX  <-> TX
GND <-> GND

# screen -L /dev/ttyAMA0 115200,-parenb,-cstopb,cs8
```

Probable serial parameters: 115200, 8N1. Tests confirm 3.3v [by following this tutorial](http://www.devttys0.com/2012/11/reverse-engineering-serial-ports/).

[The "mini UART" seems problematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) because of the fixed frequency so I will disable bluetooth and use the PL011 UART via /dev/ttyAMA0.

I have read that I can also use any GPIO as TX and RX but maybe this could add some more problems since I would need to find or program a driver?

Also note that I use a custom 64Bit custom kernel/OS with the kernel configured only for this purpose. I know about USB to TTL cable and ordered one... I have some basic electronic components and tools if required but would prefer a direct connection if this is realizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work.

You could bit bang a serial link on other GPIO but as you say you would have to write your own drivers.

Another alternative is to use a USB serial dongle.  You could plug the USB end into the Pi.

Comment: Thanks I will accept your answer if it works as is. I know about the dongle and ordered one today and then thought about the pi that I already have.

Comment: It works with "enable_uart=1" "pi3-disable-bt" and removing all the "console=xxx" from the cmdline. The mini UART printed only garbage.